# Ready to develop k8s distribution?

Tags: linux, software-development

I'm looking for distribution/configuration/anything, that will allow skip most of initial setup burden like installing ci/cd, container registry, git hosting and so on, something like Openshift/OKD/(RH code ready containers is not an option too), but manageable on single 2core 8gb node. Is there are any k8s templates/distributions like this?
I in the end i need to have k8s cluster with keycloak, cockroachdb, and my app running in it.
The closest what i can find is Gitlab+Keel.